# How to perform windowed aggregations on top of windowed aggregations

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

**Tl;dr**:

1. Why is there no analogue of no analogue of [TimeWindowedKStream](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/TimeWindowedKStream.html) for KTable?
2. How can I do a windowed aggregation of a KTable with the current API?

   - a) Map `Windowed<MyKey>` to new Timescale and treat this as normal aggregation
   - b) Convert Ktable to Stream and do the state management manually
   - c) Something else
   - d) Please don't

---

We have a infinite retention topic in Kafka with "financial transactions" which is a stream of events that contain a `BigDecimal` revenue value and a few metadata. To speed up our reporting we would like to pre-aggregate these revenues on **different window durations: Hour, Day, Month, and Year**.

The calculation of the events is pretty standard:

```
  .groupBy((key, value) -> new MyKey(value.getA(), value.getB()),
                        Grouped.with(myKeySerde, financialTransactionSerde))
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(WINDOW_DURATION).grace(GRACE_PERIOD))
                .aggregate(BigDecimalSummaryStatistics::new,
                        (aggKey, newValue, aggValue) -> {
                            aggValue.accept(newValue.getRevenue());
                            return aggValue;
                        },
                        Materialized.<MyKey, BigDecimalSummaryStatistics, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>
                            with(myKeySerde, revenueSerde)
                       .withRetention(RETENTION_PERIOD))
```

`BigDecimalSummaryStatistics` is a custom class in analogy to `java.util.DoubleSummaryStatistics` because we are also interested in `min`, `max` and `count`. The name for the key is highly abbreviated for readability.

(Comments on the code are always appreciated.)

The output is obviously a `KTable` which we write into a compacted topic. This "hourly-revenue" topic is

```
            Produced.with(new WindowedSerdes.TimeWindowedSerde<>(myKeySerde), revenueSerde)
```

---

Now to the fun part: **I would like to perform the aggregations for coarser timescales on the output of the hourly aggregation**. This has several reasons:

- Workload: If the topic is already compacted or we decide to use suppression, the number of events to process are far fewer
- Schema: The source topic is quite messed up (think multiple schemas and no schema registry), outside our control to modify and too large to persist in a "clean" topic. Currently we deserialize that as `byte[]` and have a huge and costly `Transformer` at the beginning of the topology that unifies the schema in-place (Feedback apprciated). So it would be a huge advantage to only go through that mess once.

However, for `Ktable` there is no analogue of [TimeWindowedKStream](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/TimeWindowedKStream.html). The graphic below is taken from the developer guide and illustrates this point rather explictly: KGroupedTable aggregations are

> Always non-windowed

[image]
The fact, that it is not allowed this explicitly makes me believe there is something I am overlooking, but I don't see a conceptional problem. For windowed Aggregation I need to maintain a `WindowStore` with all events that fall into a window. Couldn't this be fed from a Ktable with an upsert instead of an insert just as well? **Is there a reason why windowing on a KTable cannot work?**

And finally: **How can I work around this?** I see two ways:

1. map `Windowed<MyKey>` to `Windowed<MyKey>` and replace the `startMs` by

```
windowed.window().startTime().atZone(GERMAN_TIME_ZONE_ID).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).toInstant().toEpochMilli()
```

```
In this case, I need to write a custom transformer to properly implement the grace period and I also have to use a `KeyValueStore` rather than a `WindowStore`. In essence, I need to manually to everything `windowedBy` would do under the hood. I already implemented this and it passes all integration tests, but it feels like it's not supposed to be done this way.
```

2. convert the KTable back to KStream and use a windowed aggregation again. In this case I would need keep the state of the Kstream saved somewhere, maybe a HashMap inside the `aggregate function` to implement the semantics of an updatestream. I tried this before. It was slow, buggy and extremely hard to maintain but it worked. I find this solution terrible because the only reason KTable exists is so that I don't do something like this.

Otherwise I could just bite the bullet and do the aggregation on the raw data directly. I described the drawbacks above already.

---

To summarize again:

1. Why is there no analogue of no analogue of [TimeWindowedKStream](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/TimeWindowedKStream.html) for KTable?
2. How can I do a windowed aggregation of a KTable with the current API?

   - a) Map `Windowed<MyKey>` to new Timescale and treat this as normal aggregation
   - b) Convert Ktable to Stream and do the state management manually
   - c) Something else
   - d) Please don't

I would appreciate all feedback and ideas!

Comment: I found a similar problem with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64634870/how-can-i-perform-an-aggregation-on-top-of-an-aggregation-over-a-time-window-in but unfortunately there was no conclusive answer